# displaying old file instead of new appended one, python

Tags: python, file, tkinter, txt

Im creating this maths game with a leaderboard that uses a text file. after appending a new entry to the leaderboard, the game only displays the old version of the file.

Below is my code. How can I edit the below so that it outputs updated entries?

```
    def saveleader(self):
        file=open('Leaderboard.txt',"a")
        file.write(Timestable.name.get()+","+Timestable.age.get()+","+str(data.percent)+"%""\n")
        file.close
        
        file1=open("Leaderboard.txt","r").read()
        headers = " ".join(["Name", "Age", "Score"])#headers for the leader board 
        output = [i.split(",") for i in file1.split("\n") if i]
        out_sort = sorted(output, key=lambda x: int(x[2][:-1]), reverse=True)
        final = "\n".join([headers, "-"*len(headers),*(" ".join(i) for i in out_sort)])
        Timestable.my_text.insert(END, final)
```

Comment: `file.close` should be `file.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have did a minor mistake, Here is the fixed code:-->

```
def saveleader(self):
    file=open('Leaderboard.txt',"a")
file.write(Timestable.name.get()+","+Timestable.age.get()+","+str(data.percent)+"%""\n")
file.close()

file1=open("Leaderboard.txt","r").read()
headers = " ".join(["Name", "Age", "Score"])#headers for the leader board 
output = [i.split(",") for i in file1.split("\n") if i]
out_sort = sorted(output, key=lambda x: int(x[2][:-1]), reverse=True)
final = "\n".join([headers, "-"*len(headers),*(" ".join(i) for i in out_sort)])
Timestable.my_text.insert(END, final)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).